The join of two set partitions in the refinement order
Let $X$ be a set. The set $\Pi_X$ of all partitions of $X$ is partially ordered via the refinement order, which is defined by $\alpha \leq \beta$ if and only if for each block $A\in \alpha$ there is a block $B\in \beta$ containing $A$.
It is well known that $(\Pi(X), \leq)$ is a lattice.
The meet of two partitions is
$$
\alpha \wedge \beta = \{A \cap B \mid A\in \alpha, B\in \beta, A\cap B \neq \emptyset\}.
$$
I'm looking for a "nice" description of the join of two partitions.
In the Wikipedia article I read

To define the join $\alpha\vee\rho$, form a relation on the blocks $A$ of $\alpha$ and the blocks $B$ of $\rho$ by $A\sim B$ if $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint. Then $\alpha\vee\rho$ is the partition in which each block $C$ is the union of a family of blocks connected by this relation."

I'm a bit worried by the term connected in the case of infinite base sets $X$ (note that the discussion of the refinement order on Wikipedia is not restricted to finite base sets). Does this description of the join still make sense in the infinite case? How is connected defined?
Is there another good description of the join?

It seems you are worried that one may have to deal with an infinite sequence of connected blocks to form the join of two partitions.
One can see that no infinite sequence will ever be needed if we show that the definition you mentioned works considering only finite sequences, i.e., if we consider only finite sequences, that is enough to obtain a partition $\theta$ containing both $\alpha$ and $\rho$.
Clearly the relation thus obtained contains both $\alpha$ and $\rho$ and it covers $X$.
Suppose $C$ is a block of the relation $\theta$ thus defined, and $x,y \in C$.
It doesn't necessarily follow that $x,y \in A \in \alpha$ or $x,y \in B \in \rho$, but it does follow that there exist $A_0,A_1,\ldots,A_n \in \alpha$ and $B_1,\ldots,B_n \in \rho$ such that
$$x \in A_0 \sim B_1 \sim A_1 \sim \cdots \sim B_n \sim A_n \ni y.$$
Now it follows that if $x \in D$, for some other block $D$ of $\theta$, then so does $y$, whence if $C \cap D \neq \varnothing$, then $C \subseteq D$, and by symmetry of this reasoning, $C=D$.
I didn't separate the case in which $C$ might be a singleton (in that case $C$ is a block of both $\alpha$ and $\rho$).
I also didn't prove that $\theta$ is the least upper bound of $\alpha$ and $\rho$, but it seems that that is beyond the point of your post, and is clearly understood once the problem of the connectedness is solved.
